# How to reference resources in the default value of a Terraform variable(type: tuple(object))?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to deploy multiple ec2 instances. This requires a variable below.

Post my variables:

```
variable "configuration" {
  #description = "The total configuration, List of Objects/Dictionary"
  default = [
    {
      "application_name" : "GritfyApp-dev",
      "ami" : "ami-0263e4deb427da90e",
      "no_of_instances" : "2",
      "instance_type" : "t2.medium",
      "subnet_id" : "subnet-0dd2853d1445a9990",
      "vpc_security_group_ids" : ["sg-00e9778636a7aee5e","sg-082e93cadbd35fd8b"]
      # "vpc_security_group_ids" : [aws_security_group.ssh-sg.id] 
    },
    {
      "application_name" : "ssh-dev",
      "ami" : "ami-0747bdcabd34c712a",
      "instance_type" : "t3.micro",
      "no_of_instances" : "1"
      "subnet_id" : "subnet-0dd2853d1445a9990"
      "vpc_security_group_ids" : ["sg-00e9778636a7aee5e","sg-082e93cadbd35fd8b"]
      # "vpc_security_group_ids" : [aws_security_group.ssh-sg.id] 
    },
    {
      "application_name" : "OpsGrit-dev",
      "ami" : "ami-0747bdcabd34c712a",
      "instance_type" : "t3.micro",
      "no_of_instances" : "3"
      "subnet_id" : "subnet-0dd2853d1445a9990"
      "vpc_security_group_ids" : ["sg-00e9778636a7aee5e","sg-082e93cadbd35fd8b"]
      # "vpc_security_group_ids" : [aws_security_group.ssh-sg.id] 
    }
    
  ]
}
```

Because vpc_security_group_ids is bound to the specified application_name. I can hard code it by "vpc_security_group_ids": ["sg-00e9778636a7aee5e", "sg-082e93cadbd35fd8b"]. But that's obviously not elegant enough.

I tried to use local to achieve, but still failed.

```
Note: You didn't use the -out option to save this plan, so Terraform can't guarantee to take exactly these actions if
you run "terraform apply" now.
root@Will-T-PC:/mnt/c/terraform-leaning-will/Expressions/deploy-multiple-ec2-for_each-2# terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│
│   on variables.tf line 17, in variable "configuration":
│   17:           "vpc_security_group_ids" : local.target_sg
│
│ Variables may not be used here.
╵
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. `variable`s can't be dynamic which means they can't refer to any other `variable` nor `locals`.

Only `local` variables can be dynamic. So you have to use that instead.